# Separating file name in parts by identifier

Tags: matlab, split, filenames

This may be a very simple task for many but I could not find anything appropriate for me.

I have a file name: `filenm_A006.2011.269.10.47.G25_2010`

I want to separate all its parts (separated by `.` and `_`) to use them separately. How can I do it with simple matlab commands?

Kind Regards,

Mushi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend regexp:

```
fname = 'filenm_A006.2011.269.10.47.G25_2010';
parts = regexp(fname, '[^_.]+', 'match');

parts = 
    'filenm'    'A006'    '2011'    '269'    '10'    '47'    'G25'    '2010'
```

You can now refer to parts{1} through parts{8} for the pieces.  Explanation: the regexp pattern `[^_.]` means all characters not equal to `_` or `.`, and the `+` means you want groups of at least 1 character.  Then 'match' asks the regexp function to return a cell array of the strings of all the matches of that pattern.  There are other regexp modes; for example, the indices of each piece of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command 
[`strsplit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html).

```
cellArrayOfParts = strsplit(fileName,{'.' '_'});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strsplit` to split it:

```
strsplit('filenm_A006.2011.269.10.47.G25_2010',{'_','.'})

ans = 

    'filenm'    'A006'    '2011'    '269'    '10'    '47'    'G25'    '2010'
```

Another option is to use `regexp`, like Peter suggested.

Comment: Note that `strsplit` is R2013a+.